# Compact framework AppVerifier and managed code. Lots of memory leaks found?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, compact-framework

I'm trying to find an unmanaged memory leak in my mobile project.  I read that I should try and use AppVerifier to help find where the leak is.  After running the program, I got a log that was +5mb!  It had so much data that I don't even know how to begin looking for where the problem is.  I tried searching for my application in the log, but none of my methods are found.  Almost all the leaks happen within `mscoree3_5.dll`

I make some P/Invokes, use Brushes, Fonts, Pens, Bitmaps, IImages (and other Imaging API stuff) but all of them can be traced (as far as I can tell) to a `using` or a `.Dispose()`.  I might be mistaken in this assumption, but I don't know how to tell!  FxCop doesn't find any items that aren't disposed of, and everytime I read through the code, I can't find any either.

My question is, what is the easiest way to find where objects that can be disposed of but aren't, or unmanaged memory is not being cleared from within managed code?  Also, what all needs to be released, disposed of, or whatever in the Imaging APIs (IImage interface, IImageFactory, etc)

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppVerifier is a native app tool and will do you no good.  You need to use [the CLR Profiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevenpr/archive/2008/05/08/the-clr-profiler-for-the-net-compact-framework-series-index.aspx) and [Remote Performance Monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevenpr/archive/2007/10/26/what-s-new-in-the-remote-performance-monitor-for-net-compact-framework-3-5.aspx).

Comment: ok, thanks!  I actually dug hard in the vast array of information in the AppVerif log and found one piece that was good.  I had a font that I got the HFont pointer and forgot to release it.  I hope that was my native memory leak!  As for CLR and RPM, will that help with P/Invoked memory leaks or other native calls (Like the `ToHfont()` call I forgot to release) that I may not have cleaned up?